# Is it possible to export/import cpq settings

Tags: cpq

We have a bunch of salesforce cpq settings to configure. Since we are using salesforce DX, every time we create a scratch org we need to do this configurations manually. It is kind of tedious.

Is it possible to export/import the cpq settings we have saved?

Comment: you might consider Gearset, a vendor devops product that can move data from org to org, including scratch orgs

Comment: @cropredy Thank you for your comment. I am not quite sure what kind of data it is for the custom app setting - although it is from Salesforce. Is it some kind of data or metadata?

Comment: Lance -- well, that is a good question. Looking through the SBQQ__ items, I don't see an obvious SObject for this nor Custom Setting.

Answer (score 3):

As CPQ-configuration are all record- and not metadata-based, kind of a data migration tool is needed. Unfortunately the dependencies between those records are not that straightforward. I have been told from experienced CPQ devs that this is a big challenge.
So I am wondering, if one of these solutions (which I come over during my research) will do the trick:

https://github.com/dmgerow/cpq-migration-aid

https://docs.copa.do/knowledge-base/how-to-deploy-salesforce-cpq-with-copado

https://www.prodly.co/hubfs/resources/Moover-Salesforce-CPQ-Data-Migration-Guide.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, we have a solution to this data exporting here using a similar mechanism. But what we find difficult is about the cpq package configuration like which field should products be grouped by.